# Why do mining pools require 120 confirms for a solved block before payout?

Tags: mining-pools, immature-coins

According to [this question here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/why-is-6-the-number-of-confirms-that-is-considered-secure), 6 confirmations can be considered 'secure enough'. Some pools out there also offer payout at 100 confirms but that's still substantially higher than 6.

Why is such a high confirmation count required for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a protocol rule which prohibits generated BTC from being spent until it has 100 confirmations. The Satoshi client has an additional safety margin: it won't let you spend generated BTC until it has 120 confirmations. The purpose of this rule is to prevent long chain splits from invalidating lots of transactions that spend newly-generated BTC. For example, this rule prevented non-coinbase transactions from being invalidated after the [overflow incident](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Incidents#Value_overflow) invalidated 50+ blocks.

Some pools (e.g. Eligius) pay people by putting the payments *in* generation transactions. The recipients still won't be able to spend this BTC for 100 blocks, but at least the payments will appear in their Bitcoin clients right away.