# How many confirmations takes place before transaction is successful

Tags: transactions

Yesterday I attempted to send two bitcoin transfers from Livecoin and almost 24 hours later it hasn't been successful. When I check the transactions they have 99 and 95 confirmations. What does that mean?

Comment: 6f5d6cc00cabf6259852048eef2f8d827b7d43c08da361cec08d67e468c5e1de

Comment: f2cc94ce66eca7e55108ad0655e66ec1a97c12d05b51e8dd518a669f288de6e4

Comment: It looks like you have been bamboozled. These tx ids do not exist. What wallet / service are you using to send transactions? 
                                                         https://blockchain.info/search?search=6f5d6cc00cabf6259852048eef2f8d827b7d43c08da361cec08d67e468c5%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be1de&searchbar=search // https://blockchain.info/search?search=f2cc94ce66eca7e55108ad0655e66ec1a97c12d05b51e8dd518a669f288d%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be6e4

Comment: I sent the transactions from Livecoin

Comment: 1BABUhAB7976cP7qVcAEfUrtmitYZYkTw7

Comment: 1GKHoWnZr9vpFjzZas6138fc1QrrAndiHp sending to these two wallets

Comment: It has no outputs, only one input from `19Bb7JdyMzdgRXznTgbaMEdtod13qQUnQD` & `1Jtr7CWkWLqNsT2VP7F8uRY4CoigDxt8Jp`             , see https://blockchain.info/address/1BABUhAB7976cP7qVcAEfUrtmitYZYkTw7

Comment: what does this mean? is it that my transfer has failed?

Comment: No, it means that you never transfered anything in the first place.

Comment: Try to broadcast the transaction again

Comment: Thank you. I will try again. The money was withdrawn from my livecoin account though

Comment: Actually, you did receive 30$ on https://blockchain.info/address/1BABUhAB7976cP7qVcAEfUrtmitYZYkTw7  with TXID https://blockchain.info/tx/6f5d6cc00cabf6259852048eef2f8d827b7d43c08da361cec08d67e468c5e1de I'm not sure if you were only talking about outputs, or inputs. In this case it seems you did receive the money, if this is your external wallet. sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: But its not showing up in the wallet. Is it simply that I just need to wait some time longer?

Comment: No, it should be in your wallet right now. What wallet are you using if i may ask?

Comment: Can you explain precisely how you determined that it hasn't been successful? Be as detailed as you can.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there have been 99 blocks after your transaction that have been succesfully confirmed.

99 blocks have basically confirmed that your transaction is real, and now ( and still does) belongs in the ( bitcoin ) blockchain.

So, yes your transaction has been successful, if you haven't been credited your bitcoin, or received it, something else is wrong. Mind linking me your TXID?

The more confirmations a transaction has, the less likely it will be that it could be overthrown in a 51% attack, or for example a double spend ( 1+ 
 confirmations already makes sure that isn't the case)..

Generally a transaction with over 6 confirmations is seen as "Irreversible", (aslong as there isn't 1 miner with 51% hashpower) since it would be mathematically impossible to throw over these 6 blocks.

See [Why is 6 the number of confirms that is considered secure?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/why-is-6-the-number-of-confirms-that-is-considered-secure?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more information about why these confirmations are so important.

Comment: That said, IIRC, new coins (from mining) may require longer proofs - 100 comes to my mind for bitcoin cash on some exchanges at the moment.

Comment: Yes this is COINBASE_MATURITY and in Bitcoin is 100 blocks: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/consensus/consensus.h