# Can I spend a tx before it has 6 confirmations?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

When I got a transaction (someone transfer some bitcoins to me), can I use it before the transaction has 6 confirmations?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate; that answers why the number 6, not whether you can use it before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can even spend from transactions which have 0 confirmations (not included in a block yet) if you are willing to. That is the basis for things such as child-pays-for-parent. While it is reasonably low risk to spend from unconfirmed transactions if they are low-value, it is recommended you wait for a few confirmations for larger transactions, because before they are confirmed there is still a risk of a double-spent transaction being included in a block instead, and even after one or two confirmations it is theoretically possible (although very unlikely) for a competing fork to overtake that chain and replace the transaction. See this question for more info about why 6 confirmations is recommended for good safety: [Why is 6 the number of confirms that is considered secure?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/why-is-6-the-number-of-confirms-that-is-considered-secure)