# How could a lightweight wallet determine the validity of 0-conf transaction?

Tags: wallet, security, spv, zero-confirmation

I found that a lot of people are interested about security of 0-confirmation payments. But, it seems that most discussions focused on double-spending (like broadcasting two or more conflicting-but-valid transactions, or Finney attack), instead of the validity of the transaction. Does a merchant accepting 0-conf have to run his own full node, or trust someone else (like a public block explorer service), to validate the transaction? Does a lightweight wallet have the same security as a full node under this 0-conf scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Zero-confirmation transactions can easily be double-spent by another signed transaction spending the same UTXO, but with an arbitrarily higher fee, thereby achieving a higher likelihood of being mined first, rendering the original transaction invalid.

A merchant still needs a full-node to accept new transactions to the mem-pool, because it needs to validate each new transaction it sees.

A lightweight wallet does not have the same security as a full-node, because it relies on verifying the accumulated POW, and not the actual transaction validity. The assumption is that the chain with the most accumulated POW must be valid.

Comment: memo-pool - typo?

Comment: A 0-conf transaction doesn't yet have any accumulated PoW to verify. So, I wonder how could a lightweight wallet validate 0-conf transaction?

Comment: It cant. It can only validate the inclusion of a confirmed tx in a block header (with a merkle proof) from a fullnode.

Comment: But I see the Electrum wallet can distinguish whether a 0-conf has an unconfirmed parent or not - obviously it's doing some validation.

Comment: I am not sure if electrum always requires a full node, but the confirmation of the parent can also be provided with a merkle proof in a light client

Answer (score 1):

> But, it seems that most discussions focused on double-spending (like broadcasting two or more conflicting-but-valid transactions, or Finney attack), instead of the validity of the transaction.

That is because a transaction being 'valid' is somewhat inconsequential when considering whether or not a payment has been made. What does matter is that the transaction is confirmed in the blockchain record. Even a single confirmation may not be enough, [and so waiting for several confirmations](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/why-is-6-the-number-of-confirms-that-is-considered-secure) will mean a higher probability of a permanently confirmed payment.

Obviously, an invalid transaction is no good, but there are also no guarantees that a valid, but unconfirmed transaction will eventually be included in the blockchain.

This isn't to say that you should never, ever accept a 0-conf payment. Perhaps you run a service where the risk of a double-spent payment is somewhat inconsequential to the way you make money. If a customer misbehaves, you cut them off, and thats the end of it. No major loss on your part.

But if your job is to sell *very* expensive rocket ships, you should probably wait for several confirmations before you allow your customer to blast off, in case they maliciously double-spend the payment to you, and get a sweet new rocket ship free of charge.

> Does a lightweight wallet have the same security as a full node under this 0-conf scenario?

I think the reason that the attacks you listed are often mentioned is because the more important point is that **'0-conf' transactions are inherently insecure**, and those are the sorts of attacks that are the reason for this.  It is of lesser importance whether your wallet/node can confirm just the validity of the transaction or not.

But to answer your question more directly, I think a lightweight wallet will have a difficult time figuring out whether a transaction is valid or not, without just validating all of the data itself locally anyways.